# Cannot login into Trac via tracd

Tags: authentication, trac

I need to use Trac for project management issues, but cannot setup authentication.
I use the [following link](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#UsingAuthentication).
There is no Apache server on my VPS needed, so I use default **tracd** server.

Following command is used for launching service:

```
tracd -s --port 8000 --basic-auth="myproj,/home/git/trac/myproj/
.htpasswd,myproj" /home/git/trac/myproj
```

In .htpasswd file follwing line is presented:

```
admin:f5a9455f6b064fd41d833d3f8f1376fb
```

where

> f5a9455f6b064fd41d833d3f8f1376fb

is a password encrypted by MD5. This MD5 hash has been generated by online generator due to lack of `htpasswd.py` and `htdigest.py` in my installation (at least I did not manage to find it).

Actually, I was trying another encryptors (such as SHA-1 or SSHA) but with the same output.

When I try to login into trac via corresponding button in the top right corner, I get an error 401:

```
[29/May/2016 09:04:19] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 401 -
[29/May/2016 09:04:27] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 401 -
[29/May/2016 09:04:48] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[29/May/2016 09:04:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[29/May/2016 09:04:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

And the browser window for authentication appears again and again. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: You can download `htpasswd.py` provided by Trac [here](https://trac.edgewall.org/export/14812/tags/trac-1.0.11/contrib/htpasswd.py). `htpasswd` is also available as a shell command after installing Apache.

Comment: Thank you! you gave me correct way. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for RjOllos who helped me to find the solution.

The key of problem was hidden in password generation, as I expected. Probably it is possible to use the file `htpasswd.py` that was provided in the comment above. But I've done following:

Check if htpasswd utility exists:

```
which htpasswd
```

if there is a following output

```
root@server1:~# which htpasswd
/usr/bin/htpasswd
root@server1:~#
```

you just can skip the next step.

If not, you need to install apache-utils by command:

```
apt-get install apache2-utils
```

Then you can generate a password for a new user:

```
htpasswd -c /home/git/trac/myproj/.htpasswd new_user
```

After execution you will be prompted to type a password for 'new_user'.

Finally, call the command provided above

> tracd -s --port 8000 --basic-auth="myproj,/home/git/trac/myproj/
>   .htpasswd,myproj" /home/git/trac/myproj